# c++ dynamic string array allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, allocation

Before I start, I should mention that **I cannot use a vector** in this program.

Hey all, I'm making a program for "The Big Three" and came to a problem. The user can enter there name once, and then they can type courses they're enrolled in. They can type in as many courses as they like, but when they type in "done", they're done entering things, and the array should be made according to how many courses they typed in.

Now without the use of a vector, I must delete the array to free resources, then re-create it with the new size because the user enters another class, and then when they're done, it copies these tempCourses into an array string pointer called "vals".

Here's the method that I'm having trouble with :

```
    void Student::getStudentInput()
    {
        cout << "Enter Student name: ";
        cin >> this->name;
        string *tempCourses;
        tempCourses = new string[];
        stringstream strStream;
        string x = "";
        int numcourses = 0;

        while (x.compare("done") != 0)
        {

            cout << "Enter a new Course: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << " " << endl;

            if (x.compare("done") != 0)
            {
                delete[] tempCourses;
                numcourses++;
                tempCourses = new string[numcourses]; 
                for (int i = 0; i < numcourses; i++)
                {
                    tempCourses[i] = x;
                    x = "";
                }
            }

        }

        this->size = numcourses;
        vals = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            vals[i] = tempCourses[i];
        }       
    }
```

It's just printing out one course that I've entered onto the screen (because of the delete[] tempCourses), but I'm not sure how to get around this since I have to delete the array in order to make a new one with a bigger size.

Any info is appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: `tempCourses = new string[];` is not valid C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, ::rollseyes:: I don't see at as a shout, but as a noobie making sure we pay attention.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Well ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING, there are better ways to emphasize stuff in markup.  Simply edit if you think this could be improved. Too much eyerolling might cause falling one or both just out of their designated places.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, lmao. Already done the edit. It's being reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're deleting `tempCourses` too soon. Change the code as follows:

```
        if (x.compare("done") != 0)
        {
            auto newCourses = new string[numcourses+1]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < numcourses; i++)
            {
                newCourses[i] = tempCourses[i];
            }
            newCourses[numcourses++] = x;
            delete[] tempCourses;
            tempCourses = newCourses;
        }
```

Comment: thank you! Works perfectly now. Didn't think of another array. Although doesn't newCourses have to be deleted? Or does it auto delete? I've never used "auto" before.

Comment: @GregMiller, No, `newCourses` doesn't need to be deleted because it's being assigned to `tempCourses` and the previous allocation to `tempCourses` is being deleted before the reassignment.

Comment: @GregMiller `auto` doesn't imply auto-delete. Don't use raw pointers, or `new` `delete`, that simple.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the help guys

Comment: @GregMiller as πάντα ῥεῖ mentioned `auto` means "infer the type from the expression on the right-hand side of the ="

Answer (score 0):

Your method is rather inefficient, as you re-allocate and copy *all* previously entered `string`s *each time* a new `string` is entered. That makes it `n` allocations and `n*(n-1)/2` copies, each of which may require another allocation (for sufficiently long `string`s).

In comparison, `std::vector` (which you are dodging) *doubles* the allocated memory each time it runs out of memory. While this potentially wastes some memory, it avoids the many re-allocations and copying. Furthermore, `std::vector` also avoids the copying of the `string`s by *moving* them.

This latter optimisation is in fact trivial to add to your code via

```
newCourses[i] = std::move(tempCourses[i]);
```